# Completing the task started after viewController deallocated in Swift

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller-lifecycle

Sorry if this is a basic question but I'm kinda confused about the lifecycle of viewControllers.

So I want to initiate a task flow when a specific viewController load on screen in my iOS application.  But I want to ensure **2** things here;

1. User can switch screens during task run so application should not block.
2. The task should finish even after user switched screen and viewController deallocated from the memory.

**Important notes;**

1. Fortunately, The task I want to iniate has no dependencies to the viewController.(no specific variables, methods).
2. Also the task will be consist of concurrent programs running using taskGroup and sequential tasks which depends on the completion of the other. Some of these are also async service requests.
3. None of the tasks will make updates in the UI so all task can be run in background.

**So what I thought of doing is;**

1. Creating a class for the task to run
2. Creating an instance of this class in viewDidLoad() method of the mentioned viewController.

What I'm unsure of is whether deallocation of viewController will cause to the instance also being removed from the memory?
Or creating a strong reference for this class to be sure that its not removed will block the viewController being deallocated preventing user from switching screens?

So what would be the correct approach here?

Comment: You could use a shared instance (Singleton Pattern). It depends also what you do when the tasks are finished (do you save results somewhere?)

Comment: What should happen if the user visits the same view controller again? Do you want another instance of the task to be started? What happens when the task finishes (regardless of whether the user is still on the view controller or not)?

Comment: @Larme When the tasks are finished a service call is made to save the results to the database. I don't want another instance of the task to be started, but if it is already finished and viewController is visited again, then another instance of the task should be started. I'm trying to implement a singleton approach now. 

`class TaskManager {
    static let instance = TaskManager()
    ...
  }`
Thank you for the advice

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.